# How to find the column by using date references?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with tables, therefore they all are reference in `ListObjects`. I need to know the column of a date in a `ListObjects.HeaderRowRange` is, by using the range inside another table. I tried `find` and `match` method. As in the following example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim SourceTbl As ListObject
    Dim ResultTbl As ListObject

    Set SourceTbl = WSEscoreCocho.ListObjects("TBEscore")
    Set ResultTbl = WSBD.ListObjects("TBBD")
    Set myrange = ResultTbl.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange

    For Each mycell In myrange
        mycell.Value = SourceTbl.HeaderRowRange.Find(mycell.Offset(0, -1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        mycell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(mycell.Offset(0, -1).Value, SourceTbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)
    Next mycell

End Sub
```

But is not working. This code returns "the object variable has not been defined". The problem seems to be in the storage of the data. My first `mycell.offset(0,-1).value`  is 09/03/2020 (dd/mm/yy). No quotes. I tried `Clng()`and `Cdate`. How can I come around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve it by just declaring `mycell.offset(0,-1).value` as a `string`. The code would be:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim SourceTbl As ListObject
    Dim ResultTbl As ListObject
    Dim mydate as String

    Set SourceTbl = WSEscoreCocho.ListObjects("TBEscore")
    Set ResultTbl = WSBD.ListObjects("TBBD")
    Set myrange = ResultTbl.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange

    For Each mycell In myrange
       mydate = DateSerial(Year(mycell.Offset(0, -1).Value), Month(mycell.Offset(0, -1).Value), Day(mycell.Offset(0, -1).Value)) 
       mycell.Value = SourceTbl.HeaderRowRange.Find(mydate, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    Next mycell
End Sub
```